# Is "A Spanish Learning Grammar" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, articles, syntactic-analysis

My friend and I are talking about his renewed interest in Spanish and he is using a book called "[A Spanish Learning Grammar](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Spanish-Learning-Essential-Language-Grammars/dp/1444157337)"?

[image]

I assume this *is* grammatical since its the title of a published book on grammar, but I can't get it to sound right.

How should this be parsed please?

I keep reading it as if it should be "A Spaniard Learning Grammar"

Comment: Published books are not always correct.  The famous example is the book *English as She is Spoke* by Pedro Carolino.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_As_She_Is_Spoke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I parse it as "A grammar book for learning Spanish":

- Start with the meaning of "grammar" as "A book describing the rules of grammar of a language."[(Wiktionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar) Note, I believe that this meaning is no longer in common usage.
- Then take "learning" as modifying "grammar" meaning "a grammar book for learning" (as opposed to a grammar book for reference, I suppose).
- Finally make it Spanish. (I actually see two ways to parse this word---Spanish could be the object of "learn" or a modifier of "learning grammar". I prefer to parse it as modifying "learning grammar", but either way it has the same overall meaning.)

This is a weird title, as it's easy to get confused with the [garden path interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) of "A Spaniard [who is] learning grammar", with grammar as the direct object of learning, and Spanish/Spaniard as the subject.

Comment: The most recent citation in the OED for 'grammar' as a treatise or book is *1894   V. Henry (title)    A short comparative grammar of English and German.* The earliest is 1530.

Comment: I've never seen that definition of "grammar" so no wonder I was a bit put off.

Answer (score 2):

> **Grammar** (noun) -  a book of grammar rules.
> e.g. "a German grammar". ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grammar))

Therefore a "learning grammar" is a grammar intended for instruction rather than reference.